# Trying to figure out a responsive web design

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to figure out this responsive web design and i understand the concept and the syntax, the problem is I have no idea how to go about such as figuring out the dimensions of the div's as the screen shrinks.

Here my example code I'm trying to do

HTML

```
      <html >
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="teststyles.css"> 

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link href="media-queries.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>
<div class = "container">   


    <div class = "Pictureholder">

        <p> image here </p>
    </div>


    <div class = "Contentholder">

    <p> Model #: Samsung Appliance NE595R1ABSR    Compare
  Samsung Appliance NE595R1ABSR 30" Freestanding Electric Range With 5 Cooktop   Elements, 5.9 Cu. Ft., Self-Cleaning, Convection, Warming Drawer, 2 Chrome Oven Racks, LED,     In Stainless Steel </p>

     ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------

     <p> How Will My Product(s) Be Delivered? When purchasing a large appliance from   AppliancesConnection, a representative will contact you 48 hours prior to arriving to your     location to schedule a delivery date and a 4 hour time window. Upon delivery, your product   will be unloaded and ready for you to open and inspect. If you have chosen White Glove   service, the item will be placed in your room of choice and the debris will be removed. 






     </p>


    </div>


    <div class = "priceholder">

    <p> Was this much money </p>
    <p> this is how much it cost now </p> <Br><Br><Br><Br>
    BUY NOW

    </div>


   </div>

  </body>

 </html>
```

CSS

```
    .container{width: 990px; margin:0 auto 0 auto; position:realtive;}

 .Pictureholder{ position: absolute; left: 500px; width: 300px; margin:250px 900px 0    0;display: block;}

.Contentholder{ position: absolute; right: 0px;width: 300px;background-color: #b0e0e6;margin:250px 900px 0 0;display: block;}

.priceholder{position: absolute; right: 0px;width: 300px;background-color: #b0e0e6;margin:250px 550PX 0 0;display: block;}



    @media screen and (max-width: 980px) {



   .Picturecontainer{

    width:30%;

    }

    .Contentcontainer{

     width:30%;

 }

 .pricecontainer{

    width:30%;

  }

}

 @media screen and (max-width: 650px) {

    .Picutrecontainer{

     width:auto;
     margin:0;

    }


   .Contentcontainer{

    width:auto;
    margin:0;

  }

  .pricecontainer{

    width:100%;
    margin:0;

  }

}

 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

html {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
 }



}
```

Any tips how should I got about it?

Comment: what browser are you using? Get yourself a debugger. I use firebug for Firefox, pretty easy way to figure out dimensions.

Comment: does it work for chrome too?

Comment: pretty sure chrome has one built in.. try hitting f12.. It's always worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh so I realize I had to split up my div into three even parts and the css will take care of the rest.

so it was width: 990px, so I just simply made the width of the other three divs into 330px and take out some redundant code

```
     .container{width: 990px; margin: 0 auto;}

 .Pictureholder{  float:left; width: 330px;display: block; }

 .Contentholder{  float:left;width: 330px;background-color: #b0e0e6;display: block;}

 .priceholder{ float:left;width: 330px;background-color: #b0e0e6;display: block;}
```

the rest of the css should be good